# How to accept ISO date format in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, asp.net-web-api

`jquery $.ajax()` sends dates from browser as json in ISO format: `yy-mm-dd`  (or I can use `yyyy-mm-dd` if this is better) in `POST` body.

ASP.NET MVC4 Web API controller contains `DateTime` property for this.

How to get date value in any server thread culture settings?

I tried

```
 public class TestController : ApiController {

    public class PlaaniSisend
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] PlaaniSisend vali)
    {
      Console.Write(vali.date );
    }
  }
```

If server thread culture date format is different than ISO, vali.date value is wrong.
How to fix this so that ISO date format is uset for parse in any server culture settings ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can accept the data as string, and parse it with a specific format and culture:

```
public class TestController : ApiController {

  public class PlaaniSisend
  {
    public string date { get; set; }
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] PlaaniSisend vali)
  {
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(vali.date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.Write(date);
  }

}
```

Comment: There may be lot of date properties in different nested objects, arrays and lists in posted json. Answer reqires changing all DateTime properties to string and write manual code to parse them. Maybe  there is some setting in WebAPI json parser or in other place which allows to parse iso dates natively? I can change date columns posted from browser  to some other invariant format if this helps

Comment: There is ISODateTimeConverter in Newtosoft.JSON used in WebAPI. Maybe is it possible to use it for automatic conversion?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: I defined globalization settings in web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

and then, in Global.asax.cs > Application_Start, i set JsonFormatter to use the current culture:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```