# Issue with date value when sending the date in ISO format to Web API Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, datetime, asp.net-web-api2

I am using an Angular Resource to post data, in JSON format, to my Web API controller. The post contains a date field in which I pass a date value in ISO, UTC format like so:

```
2016-05-01T07:00:00.000Z
```

But when I inspect the object when it hits my Web API controller, the date value is converted to an incorrect `DateTime` value of:

```
5/1/2016 7:00:00 AM
```

When it should be:

```
5/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the value should be this because if I execute the statement `DateTime.Parse("2016-05-01T07:00:00.000Z");` I get the following value: `5/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`

I've read through various posts on the Internet, including SO, but haven't been able to come up with a solution to post dates in ISO format and have them successfully convert into proper DateTime Values.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried various things like adding the following settings in my `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

I also tried a fix outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833621/how-to-accept-iso-date-format-in-asp-net-web-api) by adding the following line to my `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

And this line to my Web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
```

I know I can change the properties that hold the DateTime values to be strings and use the `DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString)` method of generating a DateTime Value from an ISO date value, but I want to avoid having to do that all across my application which has *many* datetime objects specified in my models.

Most of the posts on SO have to deal with `DateTime` objects not being in the correct format for the response, but I just haven't found an answer to my issue when sending the request over.

Comment: Could be that you are looking at it in local time as it appears you are sending it as UTC.

Comment: @Darroll I thought the same thing at one point, so I tried something like this, `myDateTime.ToUniversalTime()` which yielded the value of `5/1/2016 7:00:00 AM`, and using `ToLocalTime()` yielded `5/1/2016 12:00:00 AM` which isn't right either.  What leads me to believe that something is wrong, is that if I execute the following statement: `DateTime.Parse("2016-05-01T07:00:00.000Z");` I get a `DateTime` value of `5/1/2016 12:00:00 AM` which is what I expect.